# in lxml.html how do i grab the text, children and content of children of a node?

Tags: python, lxml

I'm using python's lxml.html. I have an xpath expression which grabs the text of a node but what I need is all the text including the tags of the children tags and their content. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Could you explain whether you need "all the text inside the element", or rather, "the source code of the element"? (or something else?)

Answer (score 1):

The `Element`'s [text_content](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods) method returns the text of the element, including the text content of its children with no markup.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what tags you are using; therefore, I make up sth.

You can try sth like:

```
result = lxml.html.parse(url).xpath("//tr/td/a/text()")
```

//tr means Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are.

You can use this ('//') expression to grap the tags of the children tags.